# Handle alerts in selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to handle an alert or a frame, I am not exactly sure of if it is an alert or a frame.

I logged into instagram using selenium using below code :

```
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/');
var username = driver.findElement(By.name("username", 10000));
username.sendKeys("username");
var password = driver.findElement(By.name("password", 10000));
password.sendKeys("password");
var login = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']", 5000));
login.click();
```

Now after this executes and I am logged in I see below :

[alert or Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXECZ.png)

I am doing below do dismiss this alert

```
 function dismissAlert(){
    var alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    console.log(alert.getText());
    alert.dismiss();
}
```

But not able to dismiss this alert and go back to main window.
What is wrong I am doing here.

HTML CODE FOR ABOVE SS :

```
<div class="pbNvD fPMEg " role="dialog">
    <div class="piCib">
        <div class="dsJ8D">
            <div class="xlTJg">
                <div class="G3yoz">
                    <img height="76px" width="76px" src="/static/images/ico/xxhdpi_launcher.png/99cf3909d459.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="_08v79">
            <h2 class="_7UhW9 x-6xq yUEEX KV-D4 uL8Hv">Turn on Notifications</h2>
            <div class="_7UhW9 xLCgt MMzan _0PwGv uL8Hv">Get notifications when you have new followers, likes or comments you may have missed.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="mt3GC">
            <button class="aOOlW bIiDR" tabindex="0">Turn On</button>
            <button class="aOOlW HoLwm" tabindex="0">Not Now</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that is not alert inspect element and click on it

Comment: inspect it to know which kind of element is it

Comment: When I inspect on it I get to know it's a div with button elements

Comment: @Dhru'soni Still if it's not an alert, Can we do something to dismiss it using selenium or javascript ?

Comment: @vivek.sahni put your HTML code and error stack trace.

Comment: is it an iframe or just a div ?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I think it's just a div. I have put the html for this div above

Comment: @vivek.sahni Would you consider a Python/Java solution as an answer?

Comment: I am using Javascript

Comment: When you post HTML and/or code please take a minute to use a beautifier like http://jsbeautifier.org/ or your IDE to properly format everything. If you need help properly formatting it on the site, see the formatting help link in the sidebar of the question editor. It makes it a LOT easier to read which makes your question more likely to get answered. Thanks!

Comment: @JeffC sure will use jsbeautifier for beautification in future, but I am still stuck and not able to move forward with any of the answers provided :(

Answer (score 2):

Using javascript it could be like:

```
JavascriptExecutor js;
if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
    js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
}
...
js.executeScript("document.querySelector('button.aOOlW.HoLwm').click()");
//Or
js.executeScript("document.querySelector('[role=\"dialog\"] button:nth-child(2)').click()");
```

Using java it could be like:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".aOOlW.HoLwm", 10000)).click();
//Or
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/div[@role='dialog']//button[.='Not Now']")).click();
```

Wait a while for the element to be visible :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement dialog = wait.until(
    ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/div[@role='dialog']//button[.='Not Now']")));

dialog.click();
```

Comment: My guess is that with those class names, they will be randomized each time a user hits the page so that locator won't work... have you confirmed that they never change?

Comment: You may have right @JeffC ... I have suggested other selectors for it, personally I don't prefer the text selector since the language may change and "Not Now" will not remain the same...

Comment: I think it's a LOT more likely that the class names will change (and probably even the tags) but the text "Not Now" will stay the same... but every site is different.

Comment: Hi @ZakariaAcharki, I don't know how to use JavascriptExecuter. I am relatively new to programming. Could you let me know how to use it ? Appreciate your help. I have tried every answer but still not able to get ahead of that dialog box.

Comment: Ok first try `driver.findElement(By.xpath("/div[@role='dialog']//button[.='Not Now']")).click();` and let me know if the button is not clicked ??

Comment: NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/div[@role
='dialog']//button[.='Not Now']"}
I get this error

Comment: Are you sure the code triggered when the popup is already there ?

Comment: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function witho
ut a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
Got this if it helps

Comment: Try my update that will wait for the dialog to be visible first

Comment: I tried with the update, exactly what you have pasted but it gives me 
WebDriverWait wait  = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
         ^^^^SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
I am so sorry, still a noob at programming

Answer (score 1):

That's an HTML dialog, not an alert. You can tell by right-clicking on the dialog. If you get a context menu and can inspect the HTML, you know that it's not an alert. To check if it's in an IFRAME, you would need to inspect the dialog and then move up the DOM. If you reach the top of the DOM without passing through an IFRAME, then your dialog is not in an IFRAME.

You should be able to click either of those buttons with a simple XPath, depending on which one you want to click on:

```
//button[.='Turn On']
//button[.='Not Now']
```

I would suggest that you add a brief wait for the element to be clickable since, at times, the dialog may take a moment to launch and finish loading.

Comment: Isn't there something in selenium that handles dialog boxes?

Comment: Have you verified that the elements aren't in an IFRAME? Did you add the wait? There is nothing specific to handling dialog boxes. They are HTML like the rest of the page.

Comment: Yes, I checked it isn't in an IFRAME. trying with @zakaria explanation but getting syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

To *dismiss* the notification you need to click on the `<button>` with text as **Not Now** which is neither an **Alert** nor within any **iframe** and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `css`:

  ```
  var login = driver.findElement(By.css("div[role='dialog'] button:nth-of-type(2)", 5000));
  login.click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  var login = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@role='dialog']//following::button[2]", 5000));
  login.click();
  ```